# Why won't my alerts work after my if statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert

I've been trying to get my alerts to pop up after the user enters they enter their Lecture Code but i can't figure out what's going on.

thank you for your time btw!

```
let employeenum, firstname, surname, hours, employeecode, lecturecode

employeenum = parseInt(prompt("Please enter your Employeer Number"));

firstname = prompt("Please enter your first name");

surname = prompt("Please enter your surname");

hours = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the amount of hours worked"));

employeecode = prompt("Please enter your employee code");

if (employeecode == "L" || employeecode == "l") {
 lecturecode = parseInt(prompt("Please enter your Lecturer Qualification Code"))
   if (lecturecode == "M" || lecturecode  == "m"){
    alert("Your Pay per Hour is $575 with a teaching allowance of $2500 per month");
    }
  else if (lecturecode == "B" || lecturecode  == "b"){
    alert("Your Pay per Hour is $325 with a teaching allowance of $1250 per month");
    }
}
```

Comment: The return value from `parseInt()` will **never** be a letter.

Comment: Also please post more details of how I can earn $575 per hour

Comment: @Pointy I can say with 100% certainty that it will be a number type.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you, that fixed it. I  didn't even notice that i was doing that!  Also i wish i knew how to get that kind of money per hour myself but unfortunately i can only dream for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a parseInt on lecturecode but are using an if statement looking for a letter.

```
 lecturecode = prompt("Please enter your Lecturer Qualification Code")//you had parseint here
```